# How to declare component props on html <template> tag on Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, html5-template

I'm using Vue. Instead of declaring my templates on my javascript, I prefer to do the html way for readability and code detection on sublime, so I'm using this:

```
<template id="test-component">
  <h1>Testing</h1>
</template>

Vue.component('test', {
  template: '#test-component'
});

<test></test>
```

Works well.. but I want to pass some data to the template, like this:

```
<template id="test-component">
  <h1>{{text}}</h1>
</template>

Vue.component('test', {
  template: '#test-component',
  props: ['text']
});

<test text="asd"></test>
```

Also works well, but.. I want to declare the props on the template tag for easier readability on my project, not on the javascript component function, is there any way I could do that? Something like this (doesn't work):

```
<template id="test-component" props="['text]">
  <h1>{{text}}</h1>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't declare props on the template tag like you have suggested, the only way is to declare them in JavaScript as per the documentation.

I'm not really sure why you would want to do that, or how it would improve readability. Props are a part of the component definition itself, not the template. Not all props might be rendered in the template either. Do you think that computed properties should be specified on the template tag too?